# How do I increase the timeout period for my stored procedure call (see error)?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
 Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Source Error:

Line 91: 
Line 92:             DataSet getData;
Line 93:             getData = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Course_NewReportGet_Get_Sav", objPara);
Line 94: 
Line 95:             foreach (DataRow dr in getData.Tables[0].Rows)


Source File: c:\Users\Ryan\bancroft archive\santiago\santiago code\trunk\admin\tools\Optimus.aspx.cs    Line: 93

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950890
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846875
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +130
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +94
   Mexico.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters) +149
   Mexico.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters) +93
   admin_tools_Optimus.GetUsers() in c:\Users\Ryan\bancroft archive\santiago\santiago code\trunk\admin\tools\Optimus.aspx.cs:93
   admin_tools_Optimus.GetCompanies() in c:\Users\Ryan\bancroft archive\santiago\santiago code\trunk\admin\tools\Optimus.aspx.cs:75
   admin_tools_Optimus.Proceed(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ryan\bancroft archive\santiago\santiago code\trunk\admin\tools\Optimus.aspx.cs:43
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Comment: ConnectionTimeout Property is Read Only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps this doesn't apply, but I think it should be mentioned none the less.  The default CommandTimeOut is 30 seconds.  This should be plenty of time for any actions that are happening in 99.9% of a web application.  Unless you are absolutely sure that the action should take longer than that, you should spend your time trying to optimize the sql so that it returns in <30 seconds.  Proper indexing is a good place to start for that.

Comment: this is actually a one time deal, i'm trying to do a massive conversion of data but it keeps timing out, even after i set the timeout to 5000

Comment: @Ryan: If it's a one time deal, use the sql manager to execute your query or queries.

Comment: Good recommendation, but unfortunately it doesn't answer the OP's question.  There are a number of cases where running a very long query against a DB is your only option.  Changing SqlCommand.CommandTimeout will work in this case.

Answer (score 18):

You can raise the timeout period on the command by setting the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property.

Comment: I know this is old but I want a down vote ( but I can't because of my low reputation ). He can't use 'SqlCommand.CommandTimeout' because he his using SqlHelper class by Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.

Answer (score 10):

Then add it in the connection string:

```
server={servername};database={dbname};uid={username};pwd={password};Connect Timeout=600
```

Comment: Isn't the OP trying to find out how to increase command timeout? You cannot change that from connection string. @JP Alioto's answer is the closest to what is being asked

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Al because 30 seconds should be plenty.  Making the timeout period longer is really only a bandage to the underlying problem.

In my experience the stored proc is too expensive 90% of the time.  When I was reviewing these errors last, I had a general rule of thumb that no stored proc cost more than 1.00.  The more expensive they are, the greater the risk we had of blocking and generating these exceptions.

Comment: How do you know what the performance criteria is for this routine? Maybe its a background job that does a lot in one Stored proc

Comment: Then clearly this advice does not apply.  Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 2):

the used query wasn't optimized for the amount of data. In our case we have purged unused data, but an better option should be optimizing the query or to have a look at the housekeeping. After the action we didn't receive the error anymore. Ofcourse it depends on the situation in which you receive this error and if this solution will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding "Connect Timeout=90" to the connection string. If your query is taking longer than 30 seconds though you should really consider optimizing the query somehow. Indexes may need to be added or a view might need to be created, etc.

**Edited to correct issue pointed out by @Stijn comments.**

Comment: adding a "connect timeout" to the connection string will solve issues with database connection and not timeouts during execution of the SQL command. You'd need to set the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout for that

Comment: @Stijn, j0tt is right in that you can very well set the connect timeout via the connection string. Look at connectionstrings.com for examples

Comment: @mishrsud j0tt updated the answer after my comment, see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/841538/revisions

Comment: @Stijn righto mate! I thought you intended to say that "Connect Timeout=90" is not a valid attribute set in the connection string.