# ASP.NET / SQL Server - Timeout expired while searching

Tags: sql-server-2005, timeoutexception

We have a table called `Purchases`:

```
| PRSNumber   | ... | ... | ProjectCode |
| PRJCD-00001 |     |     | PRJCD       |
| PRJCD-00002 |     |     | PRJCD       |
| PRJCD-00003 |     |     | PRJCD       |
| PRJX2-00003 |     |     | PRJX2       |
| PRJX2-00003 |     |     | PRJX2       |
```

Note: `ProjectCode` is the prefix of `PRSNumber`.

Before, when there is no `ProjectCode` field in the table, our former developers use this query to search for purchases with specific supplier:

```
select * from Purchases where left(PRSNumber,5) = @ProjectCode
```

Yes, they concatenate the `PRSNumber` in order to obtain and compare the `ProjectCode`. Although, the code above works fine regardless of the table design.

But when I added a new field, the `ProjectCode`, and use this query:

```
select * from Purchases where ProjectCode = @ProjectCode
```

I receive this exception:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion
>   of the operation or the server is not responding.

I can't believe, that the first query, which needs concatenation before the compare, is faster than the second one which has to do nothing but compare. Can you please tell me why is this happening?

**Some information which might be helpful:**

- `PRSNumber` is `varchar(11)` and is the primary key
- `ProjectCode` is `nvarchar(10)`
- Both query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio
- First query works in ASP.NET website, but the second does not
- `ProjectCode` is indexed
- The table has 32k rows

**Update**

- `ProjectCode` is now indexed, still no luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I increase the timeout period for my stored procedure call (see error)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841509/how-do-i-increase-the-timeout-period-for-my-stored-procedure-call-see-error)

Comment: DO you **really** need all columns?? If not: select just those columns you really need!

Comment: He is not asking how to remove the error, he is asking why doing a similar operation is taking longer and how to resolve the performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the `CommandTimeout` property of my SqlCommand higher instead of making the query faster. It didn't solve the speed but solved the timeout issue.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is check the index on PRSNumber, I assume there is an index on that field and the table is very large.

Adding an index to your new field will likely fix the problem (if that is the case).

The code to add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Purchases_ProjectCode 
ON dbo.Purchases (ProjectCode);
```

Update:

I would also try adding the field as a varchar to eliminate the datatype change from the equation.

Comment: I forgot, I added an index already for ProjectCode. Still the same... Should I restart anything? Do some query or what?

Comment: How long do both queries take in SQL Management studio? and is the ASP.Net server on the same machine as your SQL Server instance?